# How to Increase/Decrease the UILabel font size along with width and height while scrolling in iOS Swift4

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have One ViewController( MainVC),  it holds one label (myLabel) and one tableview (myTableView).

Whenever I scroll myTableView then I need to do automatically Increase/Decrease the UILabel font size  along with width and height.

Example:-

**Initially myLabel.numberoflines = 2,
 myLabel.font = 30, Width = 100, Height = 100.**

**Now when ever I start scrolling myTableView then it look like 
myLabel.numberoflines = 1, myLabel.font = 20, Width = 200, Height = 50.**

In my code like
-UIViewController
--UILabel(subview1)
--UITableView(subview2)

I already tried like this

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        myLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.5, y: 1.5)
}
```

XCode 9.2, Swift 4, iOS 11.2

Comment: try doing this

`myLabel.frame = CGRect(x: z, y: z, width: z, height: z)` 
`myLabel.numberOfLines = x`

Comment: Could you tell us more detail? like how you want to trigger the transform. And you want the label change between two kinds of size or keep increasing while you scrolling tableview down and keep decreasing while you scrolling up.

Comment: @RockBalbao Thank you for your reply.
myLabel.frame = CGRect(x: z, y: z, width: z, height: z) myLabel.numberOfLines = x.

How to calculate Z value?

Comment: @JsW Thank you for your reply.
Just simply decrease the myLabel font size & numberoflines is 1  while we are scrolling up
and  increase the myLabel font size & numberoflines is 2 while we are scrolling down.

Answer (score 1):

If you have already initialized your tableview, add the `UITableViewDelegate` to your controller.
It inherits from the `UIScrollViewDelegate`. We will use two methods in `UIScrollViewDelegate`.

[image]

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

    // mark where you begin to drag
    func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        dragOriginY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        // compare your start point with the current offset. 
        if dragOriginY - scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0 {
                // the drag direction is up
                self.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2
                self.titleLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 23)

        } else {
            // drag downwards
            titleLabel.numberOfLines = 1
            titleLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)
        }
    }
}
```